# NULLIF/IIF returning undesired results when comparing Khmer to zero length string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, nullif

I have find a T-SQL statement failing to make a string NULL, if it's empty string. It's like:

```
SELECT NULLIF(N'ធ្វើឱ្យ', '') -- NULL
```

According to google translator the word means "make" on [Khmer language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khmer_language). If I try:

```
SELECT IIF(N'ធ្វើឱ្យ' = '', 1, 0) -- 1
```

So, the engine says this string is empty.

I am not sure if this is a support language issue, as [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver16#Binary-collations) I have:

[image]

or some type data type precedence casting as we have two strings. It's strange how then engine is not able to understand the string is not empty?

After all the `SELECT LEN(N'ធ្វើឱ្យ')` gives me seven, just wondering what's the exact reason.

Comment: What collation are you using? Latin collations, for example, don't "play nice" with non-Latin alphabets.

Comment: The original statement is referring column with `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

Comment: That's likely the route problem then. Using a Khmer collation, for example, doesn't replicate the issue: `SELECT NULLIF(N'ធ្វើឱ្យ' COLLATE Khmer_100_CI_AI, '')`

Comment: @ThomA it's working yes, but I may have different languages in the column, so I can't specified it. It seams I need to change the collation to solve this to something else, which I guess will be hard, as I can get `cannot resolve the collation conflict` error on other places. Or to change the code to for NULL-ing empty string, which is again bad because I have used this syntax a lot :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the `NULLIF` is  in your `SELECT` and this is for presentation or final consumption, rather than in something like the `WHERE` or an `ON` (if it is, this is likely an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info)).

As mentioned in the comments, Latin collations don't "play nice" with non-Latin alphabets (or emoticons). As a result the comparison of `N'ធ្វើឱ្យ'` and `''` is resulting in them being treated as equal even though they clearly aren't.

If you were solely working with Khmer text I would have suggested you change the collation to a Khmer colation (such as `Khmer_100_CI_AI`), however, as you have many languages a binary collation would likely be better™. Then, if needed, you can `COLLATE` the value back to the database default:

```sql
SELECT NULLIF(N'ធ្វើឱ្យ' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, '') COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT; --ធ្វើឱ្យ

SELECT IIF(N'ធ្វើឱ្យ' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN = '', 1, 0) -- 0
```